# How can i get the search results of a word in txt file from a Wikipedia site using bs4/python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I searched a word namely 'Eudicots' in a wikipedia page. [The search url shows 262 titles](https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=specal:Search&limit=500&offset=0&profile=default&search=Eudicots&searchToken=el6ff57fwb13955y5xz3y1yt9). How can i write the titles in a txt file. Is it possible by BeautifulSoup4/python? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=specal:Search&limit=500&offset=0&profile=default&search=Eudicots&searchToken=doo0wuq364b1m60hlcb894gt6'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

t_tags = soup.find_all('div', class_="mw-search-result-heading")
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
    for t in t_tags:
        print(t.text, file=f)
```

out:

```
இருவித்திலைத் தாவரம் 
கழுதைப்பிட்டி-மூலிகை 
ஃபபேசியே பூக்குடும்பத்தின் பேரினங்கள் பட்டியல் 
வில்வம் 
பாலை (மரம்) 
சந்தனம் 
ஆத்தி 
தோடம்பழம் 
வேம்பு 
நெல்லி 
செங்கொடுவேரி 
கரந்தை
```

Comment: Earlier, actually i confused with, how to give the url in requests. Now, i learned about r = requests.get(url) method. Thanks brother.